# JS Json Schema - AJV

Tags: javascript, ajv

I'm using AJV (JS JSON Schema Validator), and I'm trying to find a way to extend the types it supports.

I'm getting this error because In the schema I have a custom type (DocumentReference that I'm validating in python - jsonschema as well)

```
Error: schema is invalid: data.properties['allow'].properties['custom_signature'].type should be equal to one of the allowed values, data.properties['allow'].properties['custom_signature'].type[0] should be equal to one of the allowed values, data.properties['allow'].properties['custom_signature'].type should match some schema in anyOf
    at Ajv.validateSchema (ajv.js?ea76:183)
    at Ajv._addSchema (ajv.js?ea76:312)
    at Ajv.compile (ajv.js?ea76:112)
    at eval (configs.js?76ed:66)
```

This is a small sample of the schema:

```
"custom_signature": {
    "type": [
        "DocumentReference",
        "object",
        "null"
    ]
},
```

In python jsonschema there is a way to extend the types and define how you want to validate them, is there some equivalent in AJV?

```js
var json = {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "custom_signature": {
      "type": [
        "DocumentReference",
        "null",
        "object"
      ]
    }
  }
};

const ajv = new Ajv({
  allErrors: true
});
console.log(ajv);
const validate = ajv.compile(json);
console.log(validate({'custom_signature': {}}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ajv/6.4.0/ajv.min.js"></script>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mhkge5qp/16/)

Comment: I've never used AJV personally, but looking at the error, could you not add `"custom_signature"` to `data.properties['allow']` by any chance?

Comment: The base draft07 contains the following types:
"array", "boolean", "integer", "null", "number", "object", "string"
I want to extend these, in the error, it says that the type[0] is no one of the known values

Comment: Could you provide a little more source code, I *may* have found a solution to your problem, but I'm not sure 100% sure as to what your source code does atm.

Comment: When I **tried** this, it worked fine? - [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mhkge5qp/10/)

Comment: The json schema should look different than what you did [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mhkge5qp/16/)

Comment: Well I've been digging away at this problem, simplest solution is to just change `custom_signature.type` to something like `custom_signature.Type` or add an s on the or `obj_type` end, etc. I mean you could hack ajv about, but just changing the name from `type` would by far be the easiest solution possible. Clearly ajv doesn't play to well with instances such as this?

Answer (score 0):

I just made a module to simplify some AJV issues. It also includes a new function called .addType():

Github: https://github.com/webarthur/super-ajv

NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/super-ajv

```
const ajv = new Ajv()

ajv.addType('mongoid', {
  compile: function () {
    return function (data) {
      const re = /^(?=[a-f\d]{24}$)(\d+[a-f]|[a-f]+\d)/i
      return re.test(data)
    }
  }
})

const schema = {
  properties: {
    user_id: { type: 'mongoid' }
  }
}
```

You can also:

```
const schema = {
  properties: {
    '*name': 'string',
    '*email': 'email',
    'age': 'number',
    '*message': 'string',
  }
}
```

Enjoy!